# Is there a way to work with vaadin and jpa without JpaContainer?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, vaadin

I'm trying to do a simple prove of concept with Vaadin and JPA Persistence layer.

I have a Bean with @OneToMany relationships with fetchType = Lazy and when I trying to add a collection of this beans into a table with my DAO. I have the next exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: common.domain.Bill.detail, no session or session was closed
```

Is there a way to work with Vaadin and JPA without a JPAContainer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Bean(Item)Container and add your entities there.

If you just use a container you have no more lazy loading like you have with a JPAContainer.

Components which use containers still do lazy loading from the container but all objects are kept in the container.
Lazy loading for the container then have to be done by yourself.

For more information about Bean(Item)Container and Containers in general [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am using EntityContainer class from [lazyquerycontainer](http://vaadin.com/addon/lazy-query-container) addon. As name suggests, it supports lazy loading. It just works :)

Some sample code:

```
    resultsTable = new Table();

    resultsTable.setSelectable(true);
    resultsTable.setCaption("JpaQuery");
    resultsTable.setPageLength(40);
    resultsTable.setImmediate(true);
    resultsTable.setEditable(false);
    resultsTable.setWriteThrough(true);

    container = new EntityContainer<Call>(em, false, true, true, Call.class, 100, new Object[] {"imsi"}, new boolean[] {true});

    container.addContainerProperty(LazyQueryView.PROPERTY_ID_ITEM_STATUS, QueryItemStatus.class, QueryItemStatus.None, true, false);
    container.addContainerProperty("startTime", Date.class, null, true, true);
    container.addContainerProperty("stopTime", Date.class, null, true, true);
    container.addContainerProperty("imsi", String.class, null, false, true);
    container.addContainerProperty("imei", String.class, null, false, true);
    container.addContainerProperty("callType", Integer.class, null, true, true);
    container.addContainerProperty("cdpn", String.class, null, true, true);
    container.addContainerProperty("cgpn", String.class, null, true, true);
    container.addContainerProperty("status", Integer.class, null, true, true);
    container.addContainerProperty("mmRelCause", Integer.class, null, true, true);
    container.addContainerProperty("rrRelCause", Integer.class, null, true, true);

    resultsTable.setContainerDataSource(container);

    resultsTable.setVisibleColumns(new String[] {"startTime" , "stopTime" , "imsi", "imei", "callType" , "cdpn", "cgpn", "status", "mmRelCause"      , "rrRelCause" });
    resultsTable.setColumnHeaders(new String[]  {"Start time", "Stop time", "IMSI", "IMEI", "Call Type", "CDPN", "CGPN", "Status", "MM Release Cause", "RR Release Cause"});

    resultsTable.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);
    resultsTable.setColumnCollapsed("mmRelCause", true);
    resultsTable.setColumnCollapsed("rrRelCause", true);
```

To filter the data basing on JQL, you can execute `filter` method passing filter string and  map of bind variables.

```
...
whereParameters.put("stopTimeFrom", filterParams.getStopTimeFrom());                    
where = "e.startTime >= :stopTimeFrom";
...

container.filter(where, whereParameters);
```

If you prefere Criteria API, you can use [criteriacontainer](http://vaadin.com/addon/jpa-criteria-lazy-container).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but...

Let's see your use case:
- Your browser request your application
- In your server side code you load the bean with the EntityManager (your bean is in the session), but its relationship instance (which is lazy) is a proxy => the relationship instance will only be loaded when you access to it for the first time
- Your browser receive the response
- You click a button (for example) which send a request to the server
- You try to add/change something to a lazy relationship
- As the proxy has no session (it was created with a previous session, but now it is no more attached to it neither to a session), it throws an exception

You could try one of the following solutions:
1- Try to merge your bean (attach the bean to the current session): `bean = em.merge(bean);` just before adding/changing the lazy relationship
2- Try to force the load of the lazy relationship when you load your entity the first time: `bean.getMyLazyRelationship();`
3- Load again your entity before modifying it
4- Change LAZY to EAGER but it is (often) not a good solution

Using a container **may** or **may not** solve this issue.

Hope it helps